# missing `show your bookmarks` icon in Firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

On a fresh installation of Firefox the "show your bookmarks" icon (control-shift-O) is missing from Firefox 59.0.2 on Windows 10 Pro.

The "show your bookmarks" icon is above the green arrow (which I screenshot from a different computer that is not having this problem and happens to be Firefox 59.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04) is as pictured.

[image: picture 1]

The following screenshot illustrates that the icon is missing.

[image: picture 2]

To create this problem:

1. uninstall Firefox,
2. re-install Firefox,
3. invoke Firefox and observe that the "show your bookmarks" icon is missing
4. type the URI: fivethirtyeight.com
5. click the star logo for bookmarking
6. change the destination to "bookmarks menu"
7. save the bookmark

The "show your bookmarks" icon continues to be missing.

In the general case if fivethirtyeight.com is not considered to be "recent" I would have to make 4 clicks in order to see the "bookmarks menu" when the "show your bookmarks" icon is missing. The 4 clicks are as follows.

1. click the "bookshelf" icon
2. click "bookmarks"
3. click "show all bookmarks"
4. click "bookmarks menu"

and that is far too many steps to tolerate.

Systems: Windows 10 Pro, Firefox 59.0.2 which is current as of 2018 April.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add the **Show bookmarks** button back to your toolbar, you need to:

- Click on the **Menu** icon (three horizontal bars)
- Click on **Customize..**
- Drag the **Show bookmarks** button onto the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this too.  On my Win10 version of FF (109):

- Check 'Menu Bar' from the upper left FF icon context menu (right mouse click).
- View->Toolbars->Customize Toolbar
- Drag the bookmarks icon to the toolbar

Comment: Don't answer old questions unless you have something substantial to add. There is an [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1312859/) 5 years ago with provides similar info